# Disable screen until a call to WCF will finish

Tags: silverlight, wcf, visual-studio-lightswitch

I made a [custom popup](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Forum/tabid/63/aft/74/Default.aspx), when the user click a button in the popup I call a WCF, in the meanwhile I want to show the refresh indicator + disable the screen - [image for demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOhoP.png).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a busyIndicator control to disable the screen and show the progression percent.use  this link for more details
[silverlight busyindicator](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use the 'busy indicator' as 'erradi mourad'.

I put it also inside a model window and pop it + disable the close button in the window.

```
ScreenChildWindow screen = (ScreenChildWindow)e.Control;
screen.HasCloseButton = false;
```